# Detox - App stuck in launch screen on iOS

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

my detox setup is working well for android but I have problems with iOS.

The problem is that the app is stuck on the launch/splash screen after loading the bundle from the metro bundler. Detox is not logging much:

```
App has not responded to the network requests below:
(id = -1000) isReady: {}

Unresponded network requests might result in timeout errors in Detox tests.
```

The setup looks like this:

**.detoxrc.json**

```
...
"ios.sim.debug": {
    "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<app_name>.app",
    "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/<project_name>.xcworkspace -scheme <scheme> -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "device": {
      "type": "iPhone 11 Pro"
    }
},
...
```

**e2e/Login.e2e.js**

```js
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../.detoxrc.json');

describe('Login', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await detox.init(config, { launchApp: false });
    await device.launchApp({
      newInstance: true,
      launchArgs: { detoxPrintBusyIdleResources: 'YES' },
      permissions: {
        notifications: 'YES',
        camera: 'YES',
        medialibrary: 'YES',
        photos: 'YES',
        microphone: 'YES',
      },
    });
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('should be able to login successfully', async () => {
    await element(by.id('EmailInput')).typeText('email\n');
    await element(by.id('PasswordInput')).typeText('pass\n');
    await element(by.id('LoginButton')).tap();
  });

  it('should display the welcome screen after the login', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('WelcomeScreen'))).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

The command to observe the EarlGrey logs but that is not logging a single character:

```sh
xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "category=='EarlGreyStatistics'"
```

I am really scratching my head for hours now trying to figure out why the app is stuck and why I am not receiving any logs and would appreciate your help a lot.

**Environment:**

Machine:

```
MacOS: 10.15.5
XCode: 11.6
applesimutils: 0.8
Node: 12.18.1
detox-cli: 17.1.0
```

Project:

```
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.1",
"detox": "^17.3.4",
"jest": "^26.2.2",
"jest-circus": "^26.2.2",
```

Comment: It could sound stupid but.. have you already tried opening the dev menu of simulator/device, turning off debug mode and then turning it on again?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, if you run the tests with --debug-synchronization 200 you'll probably see that the detox sync is stuck waiting for the bundle request to finish, even though it has, note you'll need to be on 17.5.2 max to be able to see that as it seems they've broken it, I've followed all their documentation (https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1861) to blacklist the bundle URL but that also doesnt work - https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2305 - I've added some weight to this issue